# Regex for matching sequence followed by either of two another sequences

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex for java for matching following string examples:

```
my_phrases=[phrase1, phrase2]
my_phrases=[phrase2, phrase1]
```

So the sequence `my_phrases=` followed by the sequence of `phrase1` and `phrase2` in any order should be matched.
What I did:

```
 ^my_phrases.?(phrase1,phrase2|phrase2,phrase1)$
```

It doesn't work.
Could you help?

Comment: You could group them like this: `^my_phrases.?((phrase1,phrase2)|(phrase2,phrase1))$`

Comment: `.?` can not match `=[`, and `,` will not match `,[space]`

Comment: @MariaDeleva this one doesn't work.

Comment: Is this sequence the only thing on the line? Is the structure like shown: alpha chars, followed by equal sign, square brackets, phrase1, comma, space, phrase2, closing square brackets.

Comment: @MariaDeleva It looks exactly like I wrote, yes. I got the problem of `.?` not matching `=][, `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work because it is not accounting for the `[` and `]` and for the space after the `,`. You could try a regex like this:

```
^my_phrases.*(phrase1,\s*phrase2|phrase2,\s*phrase1).*$
```

But of course, the "perfect" regex depends on what exactly you want to match, e.g. whether those `[` and `]` etc. are actually optional or mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps...

```
 ^my_phrases=\[((phrase1, phrase2)|(phrase2, phrase1))\]$
```

Comment: `^my_phrases=\[((phrase1, phrase2)|(phrase2, phrase1))\]$` You need another set of `()` around the `|` or it includes the `[]`

Comment: You were faster on the draw and it is almost identical to what I was about to post. This is not the most robust way to do it, but fits the problem as written.

Answer (score 1):

This is something generic:

```
/^(my_phrases=\[([^,]+),\s([^,]+)\])$/gm
```

MATCH 1

1. [0-29]  `my_phrases=[phrase1, phrase2]`
2. [12-19] `phrase1`
3. [21-28] `phrase2`

MATCH 2

1. [30-59] `my_phrases=[phrase2, phrase1]`
2. [42-49] `phrase2`
3. [51-58] `phrase1`

And this is a bit specific:

```
/^(my_phrases=\[(phrase1|phrase2),\s(phrase1|phrase2)\])$/gm
```

MATCH 1

1. [0-29]  `my_phrases=[phrase1, phrase2]`
2. [12-19] `phrase1`
3. [21-28] `phrase2`

MATCH 2

1. [30-59] `my_phrases=[phrase2, phrase1]`
2. [42-49] `phrase2`
3. [51-58] `phrase1`